# How to get Elemwise{tanh,no_inplace}.0 value

Tags: input, deep-learning, classification, theano

I am using [Deep learning Theano](https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials). How can I see the content of a variable like this: `Elemwise{tanh,no_inplace}.0`. It is the input data of [logistic layer](https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials/blob/master/code/logistic_sgd.py).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your variable is called `t`. Then you can evaluate it by calling `t.eval()`. This may fail if input data are needed. In that case you need to supply them by providing a dictionary like this `t.eval({input_var1: value1, input_var2: value2})`. This is the ad-hoc way of evaluating a theano-expression.

The way it works in real programs is to create a function taking the necessary input, for example: `f = theano.function([input_var1, input_var2], t)`, will yield a function that takes two input variables, calculates `t` from them and outputs the result.

Comment: I cannot get the result. Let me ask in another way; how can I save the intermediate features, I mean `layer2.output`. I want to import them into weka software to further analysis.

Comment: You will have to provide a very small example code that can be run by anyone reading this question. Generate some random data, make a very small model, and then show us where it doesn't work. Why did you accept the answer if it hasn't worked for you yet? What is the actual error message?

Comment: There are two library regarding deep leaning based on Theano in the net. (1) [DeepLearningToturial] (https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials/blob/master/code/convolutional_mlp.py), and (2) is [Theano-Totorials-Master]  (https://github.com/Newmu/Theano-Tutorials/blob/master/5_convolutional_net.py). I could got the your point via (2), but I have difficulty with (1). I thing it is because the input of (1) is **index**, and I could not overcome it yet.

Comment: Well, if you know the sample numbers and store them in `sample_numbers`, then you can eval with `{index: sample_numbers}`

Answer (score 4):

Right now, you don't seem to print values but operations. The output `Elemwise{tanh,no_inplace}.0` means, that you have an element wise operation of tanh, that is not done in place. You still need to create a function that takes input and executes your operation. Then you need to call that function and print the result. You can read more about that in the graph-structure part of their [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/symbolic_graphs.html).